# Grounding two 200A panels

Tags: electrical-panel

I am looking to upgrade to 320A service.  Meter socket would be back to back to two 200A main panels.

Would the proper way to ground this be from the grounding rod to meter socket to dual lugs to each panel

Or

grounding rod to meter socket to panel A to panel B?

Or

is there a different method?

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have grounding rods you only need #6 copper if one of your electrodes is concrete encased (ufer) then the size for that is # 4 copper to the panel. Since they are back to back run to one then a jumper to the other. There are many ways the feed from back to back can be done an easy way if they are in contact is s metal feed through bushing , if a few inches between the back to back a nipple. I usually use rigid pipe and then grounding lock rings with sealing lock nuts if the panel is outside exposed, standard nuts in a wall. Some will use a pvc nipple  so the grounding lock rings are not required, many ways to do this but in residential buildings the ground conductor only has to be #4 max with a uffer and # 6 with driven rods or pipe or plate electrodes. The one thing that inspectors usually want is continuous grounding conductor, comes in clamps at panel 1 then over to panel 2 with this done there are many ways to get there through rigid pipe metallic or pvc .